# How to reduce verbosity of CriteriaQuery with EntityManager and JPA

Tags: java, jpa

In this example, I have a list of `Recipe` objects persisted to my database, in which each recipe has a `name` property of type `String`.

I have a `RecipeManager` that provides a method `Recipe lookupByName(String name)`

I've read a few tutorials and and the docs for the `CriteriaBuilder` class, and I've reached a solution, but it seems incredibly verbose:

```
    private static CriteriaQuery<Recipe> getNameQuery(EntityManager em) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Recipe> query = builder.createQuery(Recipe.class);
        Root<Recipe> r = query.from(Recipe.class);
        ParameterExpression<String> nameParam = builder.parameter(String.class, "name");
        query.where(builder.equal(r.get("name"), nameParam));
        query.select(r);

        return query;
    }

    public Recipe lookupByName(String recipeName) {
        try {
            CriteriaQuery<Recipe> nameQuery = getNameQuery(this.em);
            return this.em.createQuery(nameQuery).setParameter("name", recipeName).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Is this the preferred/correct way to do a simple lookup using the `EntityManager` framework in JPA? Is there any of this that can be cut down, or alternative methods/builder classes I'm missing that might make this less convoluted?

Comment: hello @Craig Otis! that seems the correct way to use the criteria api. Wether you wish to build upon it and simplify some of its syntax, it is up to you. It might look verbose at first, but it is just my opinion that is looks pretty concise what your wishes are.

Comment: Have you looked at  Query DSL http://www.querydsl.com/

Comment: @ArunM I have not, but I will - thank you. I'm hesitant to add another layer, as `H2 -> Hibernate -> JPA` is already getting pretty far from the data.

Comment: Let's face it the Criteria API is hideous. Give me QueryDSL any day.

Comment: @AlanHay This is my first time seeing/using it - it's pretty brutal.